# merb - wkhtmltopdf command failed

Tags: ruby, rubygems, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, merb

when am running command like this its generating pdf document:

```
$ wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf
Loading pages (1/5)
Resolving links (2/5)                                              
Counting pages (3/5)                                                      
Printing pages (5/5)                                                      
Done
```

But when using inside app by pdfkit gem it showing error

```
merb : worker (port 4000) ~ command failed: "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf" "--page-size" "Letter" "--print-media-type" "--margin-right" "0.0in" "--encoding" "UTF-8" "--margin-top" "0.5in" "--margin-bottom" "0.5in" "--margin-left" "0.0in" "--quiet" "-" "-" - (RuntimeError)
```

**what am tried:**

setting path

`config.wkhtmltopdf = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf '`

installing dependencies

```
sudo aptitude install openssl build-essential xorg libssl-dev
```

**Environment**

- Ubuntu 12.04 amd64
- merb application
- ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem sovled by changing the server port number

from

```
bundle exec merb -a thin #default port 4000
```

to

```
bundle exec merb -a thin -p 3000
```

and using the gem "wkhtmltopdf-binary"

**Explanation**

can sometimes find that the single threaded web server we use in development can cause a race condition. the browser is tieing up the one thread available, and begins a new web request to create the pdf files html, which causes a 2nd web request. Since your only web server thread is already in use, you can find this to hang.

To get around this, either run more threads. OR use another port for internal access, and have be the internal URL